# Arbitrage bot - What's the fastest way to interact with a deployed contract? JS vs Solidity

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript, decentralized-exchange, flashbots

I'm investigating about arbitrage bots operating in various dexs. I've noticed most of them use a deployed contract to call the dex contract and make the swap.

I'm supposing they're using a setup like:

```
Javascript program for fetching prices -> Call own contract -> Call dex's contract
```

I'm guessing, why use an own solidity contract and not directly call the swap function from the javascript code?

```
Javascript for fetching prices -> Call dex's swap function via Javascript
```

Whats the fastest way to realize the swap?

Comment: sorry mate. U can not achieve "fast" using JS